# What are the durable shopping bags called?

Tags: words

When people shop they bring their own bags/totes and reuse them. They are durable and come in many different varieties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are mostly called:

・買{か}い物袋{ものぶくろ}

・エコバッグ

・レジかごバッグ

The last one comes in the specific size that is as large as the baskets used in supermarkets.

The first two come in all different sizes and shapes.

Comment: have you ever heard them referred to as マイバッグ　? I think I've heard エコバッグ called that before.